# jQuery code works in Firefox and Opera,but not in Chrome and IE - not reading checkbox value correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code in my view:
    
    `@foreach (WebStill.Rola r in Model.Role)
                    {

                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => r.Selektovana, new { @RolaID = r.RolaID, @class="cbRadnikRole",data_id=r.RolaID });
                        @r.Naziv
                        

                    }`

and this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".cbRadnikRole").change(function () {
            if ($(".cbRadnikRole:checked").data('id') == 2) {
                $('#ulOrgJedinice').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#ulOrgJedinice').hide();
                $('#ulOrgJedinice').find("input").attr('checked', false);
            }
        });

        $(".cbRadnikRole").change();
    });
```

This works in Opera and Firefox,but IE and Chrome are not reading data-id correctly.
I have similar code in other view,but i use `this` insted of `cbRadnikRole:checked`,which i cant use here because i need to trigger it when page loads.

Any suggestions ?

rendered html :

```
<input class="cbRadnikRole" data-id="1" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selektovana field is required." id="r_Selektovana" name="r.Selektovana" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="r.Selektovana" type="hidden" value="false" />Administrator                    <br />
<input class="cbRadnikRole" data-id="2" id="r_Selektovana" name="r.Selektovana" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="r.Selektovana" type="hidden" value="false" />Serviser                    <br />
<input class="cbRadnikRole" data-id="3" id="r_Selektovana" name="r.Selektovana" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="r.Selektovana" type="hidden" value="false" />Supervizor                    <br />
<input class="cbRadnikRole" data-id="4" id="r_Selektovana" name="r.Selektovana" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="r.Selektovana" type="hidden" value="false" />Vozač                    <br />
<input class="cbRadnikRole" data-id="5" id="r_Selektovana" name="r.Selektovana" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="r.Selektovana" type="hidden" value="false" />CHIEF supervizor                    <br />
<input class="cbRadnikRole" data-id="6" id="r_Selektovana" name="r.Selektovana" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="r.Selektovana" type="hidden" value="false" />Operater                    <br />
```

Comment: What does the actual HTML generated by that code look like? I'm not familiar with ASP.NET, but data_id in your code becoming data-id in the HTML seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: @Anthony Grist that is just how it works, '-' cant be used.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-id=r.RolaID` instead of `data_id=r.RolaID`

Also use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#ulOrgJedinice').find("input").prop('checked', false);
```

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: That part works fine for me,my problem is with the if statement,its not getting real data-id.I click on 1 it shows me 3.And data-id is invalid in c#,but data_id becomes data-id in rendered html.